# matplotlibでグラフを作りたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

こんにちは、python初心者です。
一つ質問なんですが、for文で得られた出力結果をmatplotlibでグラフにするにはどうすればよいですか？
作成したいグラフは散布図でⅩ軸は1~10の範囲、Y軸はfor文で0~5の値にしたいと考えています。
作成したソースコードです。

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
for y in range(6):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    y1 = [y,y,y,y,y,y]
    pyplot.scatter(x,y1,c='b',label = 'test_data')
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.title('test')
    pyplot.show()
```

上記のソースコードは実行することができるのですが、Y軸で設定したfor文の結果が
グラフに反映されずにすべて[0,0,0,0,0,0]になってしまいます。
pythonに詳しい方、どなたかご教授ください。

Comment: 例えば、`pyplot.scatter([x]*6, [[y]*6 for y in range(6)], c='b', label='test_data')` の様な図を作成したいということでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/152561

Comment: teratailで解決済みの様子

Answer (score 1):

1枚のグラフに 6x6（計36個）の点を描画したいという理解でよろしいでしょうか。

であれば、単純に `pyplot.legend()` 以降を loopの外に出すことで対応できるかと思います。

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
for y in range(6):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    y1 = [y,y,y,y,y,y]
    pyplot.scatter(x,y1,c='b',label = 'test_data')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.title('test')
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

scatter部分はグラフの出力部分ですので、for文の外に出してやった方がいいと思います。
yは繰り返し結果をその都度リストに加えることで0～5の範囲に並びます。
空のリスト(y1）作成後、appendでリストにyの値を入れていきます。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y1=[]
for y in range(6):
    y1.append(y)
plt.scatter(x,y1,c='b',label = 'test_data')

plt.legend()
plt.title('test')
plt.show()
```

Matplotlibでより一般的な書き方に直して書いてみました。
参考になればと思います。